# Optional type argument for Python function to map over list

Tags: python, python-typing

Is there an idiomatic way to define a typed function in Python that ignores the `int` index parameter passed by `map` function?

It should allow for the typed function to be called from elsewhere without raising a type error.  For example I'm using the following function:

```py
def get_empty_chosen_number_count () -> ChosenNumberCount:
    return {"n1": 0, "n2": 0, "n3": 0, "n4": 0, "n5": 0, "n6": 0, "n7": 0, "n8": 0, "n9": 0}
```

Where `ChosenNumberCount` is defined as:

```py
class ChosenNumberCount (TypedDict):
    n1: int
    # ...
    n9: int
```

And if I just define it as above then calling it with the `map` function e.g:

```py
map(get_empty_chosen_number_count, range(5))
```

It gets a type error of `Argument of type "() -> ChosenNumberCount" cannot be assigned to parameter "__func" of type "(_T1@__init__) -> _S@map" in function "__init__"`

If I define it as: `def get_empty_chosen_number_count (_: int) -> ChosenNumberCount: #...` that type error disappears but then I can't call the function as `get_empty_chosen_number_count()` because it expects an argument.

Comment: There is an idiomatic way: do not use `map` (and even listcomp) only for side effects, especially if you don't need an argument. Use plain `for` loop. `map` is lazy, so without consumption you won't observe the side effects as well.

Comment: Thanks @SUTerliakov-supportsstrike  I had thought the Python way to get a list of 5 elements was to use `map` but it sounds like a multi line approach is the idiomatic way, e.g.

list_of_things = []
for x in range(5):
  list_of_things.append(get_empty_chosen_number_count())

Comment: And sorry I don't understand the side effect part.  This is a pure function that returns a new dict object on every invocation?

Comment: Sorry, I misread your question when commenting, side effects are irrelevant. Idiomatic way would be list comprehension, if you need return values: `[get_empty_chosen_number_count() for _ in range(5)]` - then you do not make a function that accepts unneeded arguments (and in general create a list by more difficult rule than `fun(x)`). `map` is equivalent to `(fun(x) for x in iterable)` (generator), and `list(map(fun, iterable))` is equivalent to listcomp with the same body (`[fun(x) for x in iterable]`). Generators and comprehensions (you can do the same with dict and set) are more powerful.

Comment: Check out this q for reference: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1247486/list-comprehension-vs-map?rq=1

Comment: Yes! That list comprehension looks much better. Thank you!  @SUTerliakov-supportsstrike

Answer (score 0):

You can use the following syntax:

```py
def your_function (*_: int) -> str:
    return "some value"

result = map(your_function, range(5))
```

This also allows you to call the function from elsewhere with `your_function()` without providing the unused argument and having it not raise a typing error.